# Mostrar un fichero binario por pantalla c#

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo un ejercicio para clase, en que me piden entrar una altura y una base para calcular el área de un triángulo, y que luego debemos mostrar dicho fichero por pantalla, pero no sé cómo hacer que binary writer interprete todo el documento, a ver si alguien me echa un cable, gracias de antemano, aquí el código (Si hay algo más que esté mal, avisad!)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int b, a, resultat;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra el Valor de la base:");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Entra el Valor de la altura:");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            try
            {
                if (File.Exists("calculs.dat"))
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("calculs.dat", FileMode.Append)))
                    {
                        writer.Write("----------------------------------------------------------------------");

                        writer.Write("Base: " + b);

                        writer.Write("Altura: " + a);

                        resultat = (1/2)*(b*a);
                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + resultat);
                        writer.Write("Resultat: " + resultat);

                        Console.WriteLine("Fitxer actualitzat correctament, polsa una tecla per continuar");
                        Console.Read();
                    }

                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("calculs.dat", FileMode.Open)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInt32());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writerElse = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("calculs.dat", FileMode.Create)))
                    {

                        writerElse.Write("Fitxer de càlculs");
                        writerElse.Write("----------------------------------------------------------------------");

                        Console.WriteLine("Fitxer creat correctament");

                        writerElse.Write("Base: " + b);

                        writerElse.Write("Altura: " + a);


                        resultat = (1 / 2) * (b * a);
                        Console.WriteLine("Resultat: " + resultat);
                        writerElse.Write("Resultat: " + resultat);

                        Console.WriteLine("Fitxer actualitzat correctament, polsa una tecla per continuar");
                    }

                    using (BinaryReader readerElse = new BinaryReader(File.Open("calculs.dat", FileMode.Open)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(readerElse.ReadString());
                        Console.WriteLine(readerElse.ReadInt32());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error general");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

        } //end Main
    }//end class
}//end namespace
```

Comment: la redaccion parece incompleta, luego de calcular el area, saltas a que tienes que mostrar todo el fichero. ¿puedes completar la descripcion del problema? gracias.

Comment: En teoría eso es lo que nos pide, que metamos datos, y que luego mostremos el fichero entero por pantalla. Simplemente no sé cómo mostrar el fichero entero por pantalla

Comment: nunca dices cuando o donde debes meter los datos.

Comment: Si tienes el texto exacto del ejercicio ponlo porque no se entiende lo que te piden. Para empezar, lo que estás almacenado en el fichero es texto con lo que no tiene mucho sentido que uses un `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: Creo que con este comentario me acabas de solucionar el problema xDD, en cuanto pueda compruebo lo que tengo en mente y si funciona lo publico como respuesta, muchas gracias!